Flag values as 'High', 'Medium' and 'Low' based on values in a column in a Bigquery table
I have a table in Bigquery with 1.4 million records. This table has 3 columns - AccNum which is primary key, AccDt which is a date field and the final column is Instances which has a random number ranging from 0 to 100,000. Out of 1.4M records, 1.1M records have 'Instances' populated, other 300k are null. I want to split this field into 3 segments - 'High' (Top 33%), 'Medium' (Next 33%) and 'Low' (Last 34%).
When calculating the split, I want to ignore the nulls, only records which has populated 'Instances' value must be considered. But for the final query, I need to get all records including the nulls. Currently, I'm using the following code:
WITH SegmentedData AS (
  SELECT
    AccNum,
    AccDt,
    Instances,
    CASE 
      WHEN Instances IS NULL THEN 0
      ELSE NTILE(3) OVER (ORDER BY Instances DESC) 
    END AS segment
  FROM
    table_name
)
SELECT
  AccNum,
  AccDt,
  Instances,
  CASE
    WHEN Instances IS NULL THEN 'NA'
    WHEN segment = 1 THEN 'High'
    WHEN segment = 2 THEN 'Medium'
    ELSE 'Low'
  END AS segment_category
FROM
  SegmentedData;

This solution almost works, but when considering the split, NTILE also considers 'null' values into the picture. I need to consider only 1.1million records when segmenting into the 3 categories, but when fetching final results, I need all 1.4million records. How do I achieve this?

How about 2 queries - one where instances is null and one where it isn't and union-ing them together?
